# Olympiad geometry: Prove equal segments

Tags: geometry, contest-math

> $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, $E$ and $F$ are six concyclic points. $AC$, $BD$ and $EF$ are concurrent at $G$. Line $EF$ intersects $\odot(ABG)$ and $\odot(CDG)$ at $I$ and $J$ respectively. Show that $IE=FJ$.
>
> [image]

My idea was the trigonometry version of Ptolemy theorem. Let $\angle AGE=\angle CGF=\beta$ and $\angle BGE=\angle DGF=\alpha$. I got
$$\begin{aligned}GI=\frac{AG\sin\alpha+BG\sin\beta}{\sin(\alpha+\beta)};\\GJ=\frac{CG\sin\alpha+DG\sin\beta}{\sin(\alpha+\beta)}.\end{aligned}$$
$EI=FJ$ is equivalent to $GI-GJ=GE-GF$. So we need only prove that $$GE-GF=\frac{AG\sin\alpha+BG\sin\beta-CG\sin\alpha-DG\sin\beta}{\sin(\alpha+\beta)}.$$This is not any much easier, although it becomes independent of $I$ and $J$.

Comment: Why would the line $(IJ)$ go through $E$ and $F$?

Comment: @Aphelli I'll rephrase the question completely.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. Since this is contest-math, please provide a source, so that we know it’s not from an ongoing contest.

Comment: This may help https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterfly_theorem

Comment: @Gokuカカロット Could you explain more? I haven't seen anything they have in common yet.

Comment: @youthdoo That's because there is really no relation between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Join J and I to center of big circle O,they intersct this circle at M and N respectively. Extend  JO and IO to meet the circle at K and L respectively. You have to show that triangle OIJ is isosceles. In this case we have:

$JF\times JE=JM\times JK=IN\times IL=IE\times IF$

Since:

$IF=IE+Ef$

and:

$JE=JF+EF$

We conclude that:

$IE=JF$

Note that this true if DC is diameter of circle DJC and AB is the diameter of circle ABI, this may helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would first consider a inversion with center $G$ and radius 1. Denoting an inverted point $P$ with $P'$, we get that $A',B',C',D',E'$ and $F'$ are still concyclic with lines $A'C'$, $B'D'$ and $E'F'$ concurring at $G$. More importantly, we have $I'=A'B' \cap E'F'$ and $J'=C'D' \cap E'F'$.

Motivated by the projective proof of the Butterfly theorem, we get
$$(E',G;I',F')=(E',D';C',F')=(E',J';G,F')$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{E'I'}{ \frac{GI'}{GF'}}= \frac{E'G}{ \frac{J'G}{J'F'}}.$$

On the other hand,$$IE=IG-EG=\frac{1}{I'G}-\frac{1}{E'G}= \frac{E'I'}{I'G \cdot E'G}$$ and
$$JF=JG-FG=\frac{1}{J'G}-\frac{1}{F'G}= \frac{F'J'}{J'G \cdot F'G}$$ and now using the last result we are done.

There probably exist a nicer proof without inversion and projective geometry, but this is the first solution that came to my mind.

Comment: Great! And welcome to Math S.E.!

Comment: You should probably write what point are you projecting onto like this $\stackrel{A}{=}$